# Babel Obfuscator - 'Renaming': Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: xamarin, obfuscation

I'm using BABEL Obfuscator to obfuscate my Xamarin application. If I compile my App in debug mode, I get no errors. But, as soon as I compile my App in Release mode, I get this error:

> 'Renaming': Object reference not set to an instance of an object

I was able to compile it in Release mode before, the error started recently. I'm using Visual studio 2017 community version.

What could be the problem? Here is the detailed error message:

```
Babel Obfuscator version 8.15.0.0
1>  Copyright (C) 2010-2017 babelfor.NET. All rights reserved.
1>  Running on 64 bit Windows process
1>  Processing myprojectname.dll...
1>  Current directory: 'C:\MY STUFF\Programming\Xamarin\myproject\myprojectname'
1>  Assembly search directories:
1>     C:\MY STUFF\Programming\Xamarin\myproject\myprojectname
1>     C:\MY STUFF\Programming\Xamarin\myproject\myprojectname\bin\Release
1>     C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0
1>     C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v6.0
1>  Analyzing...
1>  Target framework: MonoAndroid,Version=v6.0
1>  Processing System.Reflection.ObfuscationAttribute...
1>  SuppressIldasmAttribute added
1>  Running Agent...
1>  Task: Reflected enums
1>     Do not rename System.Enum types that are used by reflection
1>  Task: Serializable types
1>     Do not rename serializable types
1>  Task: Reflected strings
1>     Do not change symbol name strings used by reflection
1>  Task: Reflected types
1>     Do not rename types consumed by reflection methods
1>  Task: Exposed attributes
1>     Do not rename and remove symbols that expose specified attributes
1>  Task: Base types
1>     Do not rename types that derive from a specified base type
1>  Task: XAML symbols
1>     Parse BAML and XAML resources
1>  Task: Dynamic language
1>     Do not rename symbols used by dynamic language runtime
1>  Obfuscating names...
1>BABEL : error : An error occurred during phase 'Renaming': Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
1>  
1>  Inner Exception:
1>  Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This was a well known bug. Babel sent me the following message :

**Thank you for writing at babelfor.NET. The issue you have is a known issue we have with some license file we have generated.
Please delete your current license file and use this new license file here enclosed.
This will fix the renaming error.**